# Error: expression must have (pointer-to-) function type, visual studio

Tags: c, function-pointers

The code seems okay to me but keep getting an error that expression must have pointer to function type at the hashFunction() call. Code shown below:

```
#include "myincludes.h"

void myFunc() {
char input[10] = "abcdefghij";
unsigned char output[20];
int inputSize = 10;
hashFunction(input, inputSize, output);
}
```

Contents of "myincludes.h"

```
void hashFunction(const unsigned char * source, int sourceLen, const unsigned char * destination);
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this piece of code? I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

**Update:** I've not written the code for hashFunction. It's part of a library and I've built the .lib in Visual studio and added the includes. When I type in hashFunction, I can successfully see that it's one of the functions available. So the .lib and headers are integrated successfully into my project.

hashFunction() is defined in one of the files. Shown below(cannot paste the body):

```
void hashFunction(unsigned char * source, int sourceLen, const unsigned char* destination) { .... }
```

Comment: Do you define the function anywhere?  If so, show the definition in the question.

Comment: `source` wants `unsigned char *`.  `char input[10]` does not convert to a  `unsigned char *` when passed to a function.

Comment: also `"abcdefghij"` (which is in fact `"abcdefghij\0"`) are too many initializers for a `char[10]`.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would cause an error like `expression must have pointer to function type`. Please show a [mcve] that reproduces the error.

Comment: @Swordfish: the initializer is ok. What happens that may not be desirable (I suspect it's not the case for OP) is that the array will not have a `'\0'` element and therefore it will invoke UB when passed to library functions expecting a "string".

Comment: @pmg that condition would not produce the stated error message

Comment: Since `myFunc()` has no externally-visible action, the compiler is free to replace it with a no-op.